# cannot find module module.js:471 throw err:

Tags: node.js, windows, angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I am using 64bit Windows 8.1 Ultimate and I want to create project (ng new my-app) in the commend prompt the below error occurred.

1. installed node and npm
2. C:\Users\test>npm install -g @angular/cli
3. C:\Users\test>ng new my-app

> module.js:471 throw err; ^Error: Cannot find
>   module'C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'

Comment: See if [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following in your project root directory:

```
npm install update
npm install
```